# How to assign AWS SecretsManager policies in CloudFormation file?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-secrets-manager

i am developing a REST API with AWS Lambda, API Gateway and RDS (MySQL). I am using Node.js.

To secure the database credentials, I visited the AWS Web console and created a new secret.

Now I need to access these in my Lambda functions. I know I have to assign `SecretsManagerReadWrite` permissions, but I dont know how to do it.

Below is my CloudFormation configuration file.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aaaa-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aaaa-restapi
  

    # More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
    Globals:
      Function:
        Timeout: 100
        VpcConfig:
            SecurityGroupIds:
              - sg-041f2455252528e
            SubnetIds:
              - subnet-0385252525
    
    Resources:
      GetAllAccountingTypesFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: aaaa-restapi/
          Handler: accountingtypes-getall.getallaccountingtypes
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Events:
            HelloWorld:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /accountingtypes/getallaccountingtypes
                Method: get
      
    
      LambdaRole:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service:
                    - lambda.amazonaws.com
                Action:
                  - 'sts:AssumeRole'
          Path: /
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: root
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                      - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                      - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                      - ec2:DescribeInstances
                      - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                    Resource: '*'
    
    Outputs:
      # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
      # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
      # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
      HelloWorldApi:
        Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for functions"
        Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

In this file, how I can give the permission to my Lambda functions?

Comment: You just get the secrets in the lambda functions. It has nothing to do with the cloudformation.

Comment: @Marcin: Thank you marcin. Please provide your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Marcin: one more question, do you know how to get specifric values from the `secret` ? I can get the whole secret, not a problem but get specific values?

Comment: Sadly, you can't  request a part of a secret. You get its entire value, or nothing.

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean, after getting the secret, I should be able to do something like `secret.password` or something like that right? Otherwise I am not able to add the password to access the database and so on...

Comment: I'm not sure. It depends on your actual code, i guess. You can make new question with code example.

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, sure.

Comment: @Marcin: here is my new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68480980/how-to-extract-specific-fields-from-aws-secretsmanager-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The way it is typically done is by accessing the **secret values in your lambda function**. This would require giving **permissions** to lambda execution role to access the secret.

In your CloudFormation template, you can pass the secret name (not its value) as an **environment variable** to the lambda function.