# How to extract fields from this AWS SecretsManager JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I am using AWS Secrets manager to protect the database credits of my  REST API. I am using AWS Lambda, API Gateway and RDS (MySQL). Below is how I get them.

```
// Load the AWS SDK
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    region = "us-east-1",
    secretName = "test-secret",
    secret,
    decodedBinarySecret;

// Create a Secrets Manager client
var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region
});

// In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
// See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
// We rethrow the exception by default.
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    client.getSecretValue({
        SecretId: secretName
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
            // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
            if ('SecretString' in data) {
                secret = data.SecretString;
            } else {
                let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
            }
        }
// Your code goes here. 
        console.log(secret);
    });
};
```

Below is the output

```
INFO    {"username":"***","password":"***","engine":"mysql","host":"***.***.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com","port":3306,"dbname":"***","dbInstanceIdentifier":"***"}
```

I tried to extract the password like below

```
let pass = secret.password;
        console.log(pass);
```

It gave the following

```
INFO    undefined
```

How can I extract fields such as `password`, `username`, `databasename` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you get back `secret` as `data.SecretString`, then now `secret` just is a normal string. In your case, it is a JSON string, you must cast your string to a JSON object, then you can access the information by attribute name easily.

To do that, you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to convert a json string to json object:

```js
var secret = `{"username":"***","password":"***","engine":"mysql","host":"***.***.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com","port":3306,"dbname":"***","dbInstanceIdentifier":"***"}
`;

const secretObj = JSON.parse(secret);

console.log(secretObj.host)
```

Answer (score -1):

This Output is a JSON object literal so You Can access each object with bellow format :

```
secret.password
```

```js
const secret= {"username":"yourusername","password":"Pa$$w0rd","engine":"mysql","host":"***.***.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com","port":3306,"dbname":"***","dbInstanceIdentifier":"***"};
console.log(secret.password);
console.log(secret.username);
document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = secret.password;
```

```html
<p>
Your Password is : <span id="secret"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: No it is not. It returns `INFO Undefined`. Also this has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: @JustCause i use html in Example for easy and Better view ! I know You won't use it in html ! Are you seriously do negative vote for this ! "INFO" is in your output or Yourself Writing this string before output?